# How to correctly set PWM to control servo angle in AVR?

Tags: servo, pwm, avr

I've stumbled upon timer configuration to handle my sg-90 servo and my Arduino UNO.

**What I did:**

1. *Set the prescaler to 64 and mode to fast PWM of 16-bit timer.*
2. *The frequency is 50hz so the ICR1 is set to 4999.*
3. *And now I don't know what to do next to set the values of OCR1A without guessing them.*

From my understanding: **If the period is now set to 20ms then for sg-90 servo:**

From documentation: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf

- Angle 0 should be 1ms (1/20 = 0.05), so OCR1A = 4999 * 0.05 ~= 250
- Angle 90 should be 1.5ms (1.5/20 = 0.075), so OCR1A = 4999 * 0.075 ~= 375
- Angle 180 should be 2ms (2/20 = 0.1) so OCR1A = 4999 * 0.1 ~= 500

**But it doesn't work like that.** I've figured out that values are 125, 370, 615 - I've found these numbers in the internet (not in English language) but that guy didn't explain how he got them.

Could someone explain it to me where these numbers come from or where my calculations are incorrect.

It's not a problem with servo because with Arduino servo library everything works fine.

**Solution:**

**The document I've attached is incorrect the pulse range of miliseconds is not 1-2ms but 0.5-2.5ms and everything fits correctly.**

Below is my current code:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PRESCALER_64 (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10)
#define FAST_PWM_A (1 << WGM11)
#define FAST_PWM_B (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12)

int main(){

    TCCR1A = FAST_PWM_A | (1 << COM1A1);
    TCCR1B = FAST_PWM_B | PRESCALER_64;
    ICR1 = (F_CPU / 64 / 50) - 1;

    DDRB |= (1 << PB1);

    while(true){
        OCR1A = 125;
        _delay_ms(2000);
         OCR1A = 370;
        _delay_ms(2000);
        OCR1A = 615;
        _delay_ms(2000);
    }

}
```

Comment: research what signals servos expect to receive ... not an Arduino related question

Comment: jsotola is right, this is an AVR question, not an Arduino question, it might be better posted on StackOverflow. Anyway, if your timer period is 5000 cycles, your calculations look correct to me. (I haven't checked the timer setup.) Don't you have an oscilloscope to watch the signal? -- Concerning this "other guy": Since any fool can post stuff on "the net", doubt any information, especially if it is not explained. The difficulty today is to filter the 1% of good things from the crap.

Comment: why not use a library?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. The problem is in the document. The pulse width is not in range 1-2ms but 0,.5-2.5ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

The document I've attached is incorrect, the pulse range of milliseconds is not 1-2ms but 0.5-2.5ms and everything fits correctly.